# new constructor in OCaml function

Tags: ocaml

When writing this function:

```
let make_new_instance class_name = new class_name
```

I get the error "unbound class class_name", however, this is just a function definition, not a function call. How do I delay the "new" so that it doesn't attempt to construct an object until the function is called?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it in OCaml, which is a statically typed language. Classes must be statically specified at `new` and cannot be used as arguments to function applications. (`new` is not even a function but a special form `new <classname>`.)

One way to parameterize classes is to use functors:

```
module A = struct
  class c = object
    method x = 1
  end
end

module Make(A : sig class c : object method x : int end end) = struct
  let make_new_instance () = new A.c
end

module MakeA = Make(A)
```

but I am afraid this is far from you want.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really something you can do in OCaml. One way to see this is to think about what you would pass to the function. A class name is a type, not a value. Another way is to note that a function can only return values of one type. Different classes have different types.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change you `class_name` parameter to unit ?

```
let make_new_class_name () = new class_name
```

Comment: I need to reuse the function with different classes. How can I pass a class into this function?

Answer (score 0):

Classes in a OCaml are like blueprints, but to create something, you usually do not start from blueprints, but go to factory. So, if you need a factory that creates an instances of certain class, then it can be done:

```
class blue_print x y = object ... end
let create_instance = new blue_print
let factory instance_maker x y = instance_maker x y
```

Of course, all this doesn't make big sense, since example is very reduced, but if it is coupled with some registry, where you store `instace_maker`s, then you will get an abstract factory

Answer (score 0):

> I get the error `unbound class class_name`, however, this is just a function definition, not a function call. How do I delay the "new" so that it doesn't attempt to construct an object until the function is called?

The error you get comes from the fact that `class_name` here is the name of a function argument, but you try to have it carry the name of a class. In languages like PERL, PHP, or other similar languages, you have access at runtime to symbol tables, thus letting you define new functions, new classes, new variables, and reference them in variables. For instance, in PHP, the code:

```
 <?php

    function foo($var){ echo ${$var};}

    $bar = "foo";
    $bar($bar);
```

would render:

```
 "Function"
```

by calling the function `foo` through the variable `$bar`.

In OCaml, you cannot do something like that with value names, in your precise case, the grammar strictly expects a class name after the keyword `new` (otherwise you would be confronted with problems typically encountered in dynamic languages, ie, how to check whether the variable content is really a class) - Jeffrey Scoffield is spot on there. However, being a functional language, the usual way is to pass around functions, and apply them to parameters in other functions:

```
class foo () = object
  method m = "foo"
end

class bar () = object
  method m = "bar"
end
```

Both class above have the same class type, and expect the same arguments to create instances of them, thus you may use them interchangeably without typing issues.

```
let mk_instance toggle : object method m : string end = 
  if toggle 
  then new foo ()
  else new bar ()
```

the function `mk_instance` will produce either an instance of `foo` or an instance of `bar` depending on the value of `toggle`.

You can use that to your advantage by creating functions wrapping instantiations of `foo`s and `bar`s, and then pass them around:

```
let mk_foo = new foo
let mk_bar = new bar

let mk_instance mk : object method m : string end = mk ()
```

The above is trivial, but you may certainly envision cases with more involved class definitions, and with closures, it is always possible to align function signatures to make this easier, or embed them in sum types to indicate different possibilities.